# Term for relationship between inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Say we have the inequality given by:

\begin{equation}
\sum_i(x_i - y_i) \geq 0 \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{(1)}
\end{equation}

Certainly we can say that the inequality in equation (1) is obeyed when\begin{equation}
\sum_i x_i \geq \sum_i y_i \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{(2)}
\end{equation}

However, if I have the requirement:
\begin{equation}
 x_i \geq y_i \quad \forall i \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \text{(3)}
\end{equation}

we can say that equation (3) being obeyed always leads to equations (1) and (2) being obeyed while equation (2) satisfies equation (1) but not equation (3).

**My question is**: is there a term for such a relationship between criteria related to inequalities, where one criterion leads to two other criteria being obeyed but not the other way around?

*I understand that this question sounds a bit vague, but any idea for terminology related to this would be appreciated.*

Comment: Maybe that $(3)$ is a _sufficient_  but not _neccesary_ condition for $(1)$ and $(2)$, which are _equivalent_?

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the suggestion